# How to minimize memory usage while splitting .mp3 file into parts

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, pydub

I have a large .mp3 file (> 100 MB) that I want to split into parts less or equal 50 MB (for sending from Telegram bot). I solve this task by slicing the file into pieces of 50 minutes long.

Test file:

```
~$ file /tmp/test.mp3
/tmp/test.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 192 kbps, 48 kHz, Stereo

~$ du -sch /tmp/test.mp3
130M    /tmp/test.mp3
130M    total

~$ mp3info -p "%m:%02s\n" /tmp/test.mp3
94:25
```

Used code:

```
import os

from pydub import AudioSegment


TIME_PERIOD = 50 * 60 * 1000


def split_audio(file_path):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path).split(".")[0]
    audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_path)

    audio_parts = []
    pos = 0

    for i in range(len(audio) // TIME_PERIOD + 1):
        audio_part = audio[pos : pos + TIME_PERIOD]
        pos = pos + TIME_PERIOD
        part_path = f"/tmp/{file_name}_part{i}.mp3"
        audio_parts.append(part_path)
        audio_part.export(part_path, format="mp3")

    return audio_parts
```

It works fine:

```
~$ find /tmp/ -name "test*.mp3" | xargs du -sch
41M /tmp/test_part1.mp3
46M /tmp/test_part0.mp3
130M    /tmp/test.mp3
217M    total

~$ find /tmp/ -name "test*.mp3" | xargs mp3info -p "%m:%02s\n"
44:25
50:00
94:25
```

But consumes a lot of memory:

```
%memit split_audio("/tmp/test.mp3")
peak memory: 5061.56 MiB, increment: 5012.34 MiB
```

And takes a lot of time:

```
%timeit split_audio("/tmp/test.mp3")
1min 24s ± 668 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Is there any way to split mp3 into pieces without using so much memory and make it a bit faster?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your mp3 is kinda large, I don't think I can help with the memory.

Looks like you have to load the entire file to memory in order to process it.

If you want to make it faster, I guess `multiprocessing` can help.

Since you know how you want to split your file, each "part" is indipendent and is not coupled to the previous part:

```py
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

from pydub import AudioSegment

TIME_PERIOD = 50 * 60 * 1000


def split_worker(audio, pos_from, pos_to, dst_path):
    audio_part = audio[pos_from: pos_to]
    audio_part.export(dst_path, format="mp3")


def split_audio(file_path):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path).split(".")[0]
    audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_path)

    audio_parts = []
    pos = 0
    ps = []

    for i in range(len(audio) // TIME_PERIOD + 1):
        part_path = f"/tmp/{file_name}_part{i}.mp3"
        p = mp.Process(target=split_worker,
                       args=(audio, pos, pos + TIME_PERIOD, part_path))

        ps.append(p)

        pos = pos + TIME_PERIOD
        audio_parts.append(part_path)

        # Up to 5 parallel workers
        if len(ps) >= 5:
            for p in ps:
                p.join()

            ps = []

    # Wait for the remainder
    for p in ps:
        p.join()

    return audio_parts
```

I couldn't test this code locally, but this is the idea in general

EDIT: You can also have your process to make only the `export` part:

```py
def split_worker(audio_part, dst_path):
    audio_part.export(dst_path, format="mp3")
```

And the loop in `def split_audio(file_path):` looks like:

```py
 for i in range(len(audio) // TIME_PERIOD + 1):
        audio_part = audio[pos: pos + TIME_PERIOD]
        part_path = f"/tmp/{file_name}_part{i}.mp3"
        p = mp.Process(target=split_worker,
                       args=(audio_part, part_path))
```

It really depends how fast the line `audio[pos: pos + TIME_PERIOD]` is